# Can't change background color & outline colour of buttons

Tags: android, xml, gradient, android-drawable, android-button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/signInBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/rounded_arrow_forward_ios_24"
    android:fontFamily="@font/alata"
    android:paddingVertical="10dp"
    android:text="@string/sign_in"
    android:textFontWeight="600"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:iconPadding="140dp"
    app:iconSize="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tagline" />
```

I have two buttons in my XML layout file, one for signing in and the other for signing up. The sign-in button has a gradient background, but the sign-in button's background remains the default blue color. I'm trying to change the outline color for the sign-up button but attempts to use **`background Tint`** or **`foreground Tint`** change the entire background color instead. I've already tried clearing the cache and restarting, but the issue persists.

How can I properly change the outline color for the sign-up button without affecting the entire background and the background of sign-in button?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/orange"
              android:endColor="@color/lightBlue"
              android:angle="270"/>

    <corners android:radius="40dp"/>
</shape>
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/signUpBtn"
    style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/rounded_arrow_forward_ios_24"
    android:fontFamily="@font/alata"
    android:paddingVertical="10dp"
    android:text="@string/sign_up"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textFontWeight="600"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:iconPadding="140dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signInBtn" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the outline color for the sign-up button without affecting the entire background, use the 'android:backgroundTint' attribute.
Add the below line to sign-up button XML

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/DesiredOutlineColor"
```

Add your desired color to above line.

Comment: Already tried this. It changes entire bg color.